# Forbid users to close the Browser & Tab in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, browser, permissions

How can I forbid certain users to close the browser windows / Tab in Ubuntu? Is there a convenient way to realize it? I am open for any solution, doesn't matter if it's for chrome or Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can do it with javascript on the onclose event, can't you?

Comment: This is not an option because the users can force a shutdown of the browser anyway. So I really need a way to forbid closing the browser. 

Any other idea?